# Jetpack Compose Format Date String

Tags: android, date, android-jetpack-compose, datetime-format, java-time

Please, how do I format these date strings: `2017-04-08T18:39:42Z` or `2023-04-04T14:01:31-07:00` to get something like this: `August 04, 2017 | 6:39pm`. Thanks in advance.
I have tried something like this below:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun formatDate(date: String): String {

    return try {
        val datePattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
        val offSetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, datePattern)
        val formattedDate = "${offSetDateTime.month} ${offSetDateTime.dayOfMonth}, ${offSetDateTime.year}"
        Log.i("formattedDate", formattedDate)
        formattedDate
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        date
    }
}
```

It did not work. It's return the string passed as an argument, in order word, it's throwing an exception.

Comment: Just drop `datePattern`. `OffsetDateTime` parses both of your strings without any explicit formatter because they are both in ISO 8601 format: `val offSetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(date)`. Remember to convert the parsed date-time into the time zone that your user expects, for example: `offsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. Because your user cannot use `August 04, 2017 | 6:39pm` for anything if it’s understood at a UTC offset that they don’t know. And then use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting into the desired string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OffsetDateTime.parse` requires a string containing an offset `(+/-hh:mm)`
Parse it using `LocalDateTime.parse`

```
    val dateSt = "2017-04-08T18:39:42Z"
    val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    val formattedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateSt, dateFormatter)
    val res = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy | hh:mma").format(formattedDate) // August 04, 2017 | 6:39pm
```

Comment: Thanks @ahmed. It worked. But do you know how I can implement it if the string comes like this: ```2023-04-04T14:01:31-07:00```?

Comment: @Trailblazer you can use  `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` as predefined formatter you may check this page for more predefined formatters https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Thanks for your response @ahmed. That was what I later did. It's working.